# How do I sort one vector based on values of another

Tags: sorting, r

I have a vector x, that I would like to sort based on the order of values in vector y. The two vectors are not of the same length.

```
x <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3)
y <- c(4, 2, 1, 3)
```

The expected result would be:

```
[1] 4 4 4 2 2 1 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 226):

what about this one

```
x[order(match(x,y))]
```

Comment: This is very nice, better than the accepted answer IMHO as it is more general.

Comment: I would go as far as to say this should be in base GNU-R.

Comment: This answer worked well for me when using character vectors both for x and y. Adding a decomposition/slight elaboration as in the accepted answer would be nice

Answer (score 6):

You could convert `x` into an ordered factor:

```
x.factor <- factor(x, levels = y, ordered=TRUE)
sort(x)
sort(x.factor)
```

Obviously, changing your numbers into factors can radically change the way code downstream reacts to `x`.  But since you didn't give us any context about what happens next, I thought I would suggest this as an option.

Comment: this should be the best answer since it would work for non integer cases; or also work when there are values in `x` not in the sorting vector `y` with slight change: `x <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 6); y <- c(4, 2, 1, 3); as.numeric(as.character(sort(factor(x, unique(c(y, x))))))`

Answer (score 2):

How about?:

```
rep(y,table(x)[as.character(y)])
```

(Ian's is probably still better)

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to get order on "y" no matter if it's numbers or characters:

```
x[order(ordered(x, levels = y))]
4 4 4 2 2 1 3 3 3
```

By steps:

```
a <- ordered(x, levels = y) # Create ordered factor from "x" upon order in "y".
[1] 2 2 3 4 1 4 4 3 3
Levels: 4 < 2 < 1 < 3

b <- order(a) # Define "x" order that match to order in "y".
[1] 4 6 7 1 2 5 3 8 9

x[b] # Reorder "x" according to order in "y".
[1] 4 4 4 2 2 1 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

[*Edit:* Clearly Ian has the right approach, but I will leave this in for posterity.]

You can do this without loops by indexing on your y vector.  Add an incrementing numeric value to y and merge them:

```
y <- data.frame(index=1:length(y), x=y)
x <- data.frame(x=x)
x <- merge(x,y)
x <- x[order(x$index),"x"]
x
[1] 4 4 4 2 2 1 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3)
y <- c(4, 2, 1, 3)
for(i in y) { z <- c(z, rep(i, sum(x==i))) }
```

The result in z: 4 4 4 2 2 1 3 3 3

The important steps:

1. for(i in y) -- Loops over the elements of interest.
2. z <- c(z, ...) -- Concatenates each subexpression in turn
3. rep(i, sum(x==i)) -- Repeats i (the current element of interest) sum(x==i) times (the number of times we found i in x).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `sqldf` and do it by a `join` function in `sql` likes the following:

```
library(sqldf)
x <- data.frame(x = c(2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3))
y <- data.frame(y = c(4, 2, 1, 3))

result <- sqldf("SELECT x.x FROM y JOIN x on y.y = x.x")
ordered_x <- result[[1]]
```