# Sorting a vector with predetermined order

Tags: r, sorting, vector

I have a vector x of length 10 that I would like to sort based on the order of values in vector y (1:10). Say:

```
x <- c(188,43,56,3,67,89,12,33,123,345)
y <- c(3,4,5,7,6,9,8,2,1,10)
```

The vector y will always consist of numbers from 1 to 10, but in different orders. I'd like to match the lowest value in x with 1 and the highest value with 10 so that the output will be something like

```
x_new <-(33,43,56,67,89,123,188,12,3,345)
```

How can I do this? I appreciate any input!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort one vector based on values of another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568511/how-do-i-sort-one-vector-based-on-values-of-another)

Comment: @Andrie: there was no spotting involved.  I searched for "[r] sort vector" and it was the 10th result.

Comment: @Joshua, I saw that post but it was different from my specific problem

Answer (score 6):

```
sort(x)[y]
 [1]  33  43  56  89  67 188 123  12   3 345
```

Comment: Nice answer, beautifully simple.