# Order data frame by two columns in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to reorder the rows of a data frame by two factors. For the first factor i'm happy with the default ordering. For the second factor i'd like to impose my own custom order to the rows. Here's some dummy data:

```
dat <- data.frame(apple=rep(LETTERS[1:10], 3), 
                  orange=c(rep("agg", 10), rep("org", 10), rep("fut", 10)),
                  pear=rnorm(30, 10), 
                  grape=rnorm(30, 10))
```

I'd like to order "apple" in a specific way:

```
appleOrdered <- c("E", "D", "J", "A", "F", "G", "I", "B", "H", "C")
```

I've tried this:

```
dat <- dat[with(dat, order(orange, rep(appleOrdered, 3))), ]
```

But it seems to put "apple" into a random order. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Related to [How do I sort one vector based on values of another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568511/how-do-i-sort-one-vector-based-on-values-of-another)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reordering the factor levels:

```
dat[with(dat, order(orange, as.integer(factor(apple, appleOrdered)))), ]
```

Comment: This works great, thanks. Is there any reason to wrap the factor call in as.integer()? Removing it seems to give exactly the same result.

Comment: Sounds find - I wasn't positive if factor sort order was defined by the levels or the as.character() of it.

Answer (score 12):

Try using a factor with the levels in the desired order and the `arrange` function from `plyr`:

```
dat$apple <- factor(dat$apple,levels=appleOrdered)
arrange(dat,orange,apple)
```

Comment: you don't need `ordered=TRUE`.