# Changing the order of vector in terms of anthother in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors `a` and `b`.

```
   a =c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7)
   b =c(1.5, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5, 9.5, 0, 0)
   C=sort(a)
```

I do not know how can I create vector of `result` in terms of c.
How can I get this vector in R?

```
   result = c(1.5, 0, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5, 9.5, 0)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568511/how-do-i-sort-one-vector-based-on-values-of-another

Comment: @Stedy While I would be shocked if this question is not a duplicate, that question isn't the same at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use the vector `C` in the ordering of the elements of `b`, but rather, you want to permute the elements of `b` in the same way that `sort(a)` permutes the elements of `a`.

`order` returns this permutation.  Note that `a[order(a)]` is the same as `sort(a)` (with the default `decreasing = FALSE`).

```
b[order(a)]
[1] 1.5 0.0 5.5 6.5 8.5 9.5 0.0
```