# Sorting two vectors in terms of another in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors X and Y. So I want to sort X in ascending order and pair X with corresponding Y. Here X and Y have same number of elements.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: why doesn't `sort` work? How do the Xs and Ys "correspond?"

Comment: I believe this question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568511/how-do-i-sort-one-vector-based-on-values-of-another

Comment: Yes, I have tried that link and didn't work for me. But, just resolved it.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `order`, e.g.:

```
X <- c(1,4,2,4,5)
Y <- c(9,3,2,3,4)
X.sorted <- X[order(X)]
Y.sorted <- Y[order(X)]
```

Answer (score 1):

twin's answer should work. One suggestion (I'd comment, but I'm too lowly in my rep) is that if the vectors are very large, it might be more efficient to store the order rather than compute it twice:

```
i = order(X)
X.sorted = X[i]
Y.sorted = Y[i]
rm(i)              #clean up
```

(I'm not sure how R caches function results, if at all, but it's possible that R does this internally even with twin's code.)

It also sounds like you might want these data vectors to be more explicitly linked, in which case it may be good practice to codify that and handle them as a single data frame:

```
d = data.frame(X=X,Y=Y)
d.sorted = d[order(d$X),]
```

Comment: I'm rather sure that R would not "cache" the results of the first `order` call in twin's code. Against your approach is that making `i` will prevent the numeric vector from being garbage collected, and you might want to finish up with `rm(i)`.

Comment: Good point, edited. Thanks.