# Sorting by successive vectors in R

Tags: r, sorting

Say I have a list

```
> foo
[1] 14 15 20 17 14 20 60 16 16 12 14
```

and I want to sort by numbers in the list according to another list.  For example say I have another list like so (the sorting reference list),

```
> foo_2
[1] 60 17 14 15 20 16 12
```

So here, the original list would come out sorted like so,

```
> foo
[1] 60 17 14 14 14 15 20 20 16 16 12
```

Comment: Side note: all of your objects are `vector`, not `list` in R.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Specifically this answer in the linked duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2117080/496803 The accepted answer is a bit dubious really.

Comment: What happens when you are sorting within a dataframe, and you want to sort by one column?