# Removing non-unique values and rearranging vectors

Tags: matlab, sorting, astronomy, large-data

I worked with Sloan Digital Sky Survey (SDSS) data, and got a final data product of [this](https://www.dropbox.com/home/Stack?preview=final_spec.txt) file.  The first column is of `wLength` (wavlength) and second is of `flux`.

Storing the zeros in `zero_F` variable `zero_F = find(a==0)`, I removed them from both columns using `wLength(zero_F)=[];` and `flux(zero_F)=[];`. I want to plot `wLength` vs `flux`, `flux` is dependent on `wLength` but `wLength` contains values which are non-unique.

How can I get indices of non-unique values in data so that I can remove the corresponding indices from both `wLength` and `flux` to make the arrays of same size and plot them. Also, since `issorted(wLength)` returned `0` that'd mean that `wLength` isn't sorted out, but sorting it out will definitely change the correspondence of it's values with `flux`, how can I sort `flux`  based on `wLength` values.

I read about sorting `x` vs `y` [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13185-sorting-according-to-another-vector) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568511/how-do-i-sort-one-vector-based-on-values-of-another) but I quite didn't get the answers.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload the file to a source that doesn't require a username? Or better yet - copy & paste some representative lines which are sufficient to reproduce your problem. It'd be much easier to understand (and help you) if you also pasted the piece of code that does everything you described - you don't want people wasting their energy on writing what you already wrote instead of focusing on solving your specific problem, right?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't know dropbox has such limitations on file sharing. Would you be kind enough to recommend my some websites where I can upload my stuff for use in SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
% Get unique values from wLength
[wLengthUn, iUn, ~] = unique(wLength);
fluxUn = flux(iUn);

% Sort the arrays, if needed
[wLengthSrt, iSrt] = sort(wLengthUn);
fluxSrt = fluxUn(iSrt);

% Plot data
plot(fluxSrt, wLengthSrt)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very clean and did the work well