# Sorting an array of URLs

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, alphanumeric

I have an array with quasar URLs stored in it

```
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/0269/spec-0269-51581-0467.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/0329/spec-0329-52056-0059.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/104/spectra/2957/spec-2957-54807-0164.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/0342/spec-0342-51691-0089.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/2881/spec-2881-54502-0508.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/0302/spec-0302-51616-0435.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/2947/spec-2947-54533-0371.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/0301/spec-0301-51942-0460.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/104/spectra/2962/spec-2962-54774-0461.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/2974/spec-2974-54592-0185.fits
```

I want to sort out the URL array on basis of the number next to `spec-` and not using alphabetic order. I sorted the array with `sort` but it didn't help as it always took the `3rd` row and `2nd last` row to the top because they have a `1`.

I'd like to have an output like this

```
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/0269/spec-0269-51581-0467.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/0301/spec-0301-51942-0460.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/0302/spec-0302-51616-0435.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/0329/spec-0329-52056-0059.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/0342/spec-0342-51691-0089.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/2881/spec-2881-54502-0508.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/2947/spec-2947-54533-0371.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/104/spectra/2957/spec-2957-54807-0164.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/104/spectra/2962/spec-2962-54774-0461.fits
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/2974/spec-2974-54592-0185.fits
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will always have this pattern, you can try:

```
fileName = strsplit(myUrl, '/')(end)
number = strsplit(fileName(5:end), '.')(0)
```

Gonna walk you through this cause understanding is everything...

We start with

```
http://dr12.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/sdss/spectro/redux/26/spectra/0269/spec-0269-51581-0467.fits
```

First we split the URL on the `/` characters. This will return a vector of strings split up from this character.  Since the number to sort on resides after the final `/`, we can pass `end` to grab the last one.  Now we have

```
spec-0269-51581-0467.fits
```

Next, let's remove that pesky `spec-` from the number.  This step *isn't* actually necessary, since it's constant across all the URLs, but let's just do it for fun. We can use Matlab's substring to grab the characters after the `-`, using `fileName(5:end)`.  This will create a string starting with the 5th character (in this case, a 0) and continue to the end.  Great, now we have

```
0269-51581-0467.fits
```

Looking good! Again, this part isn't completely necessary either, but just in case for whatever reason you may need to, I've included it.  We can use the `strsplit` function again, but this time split on the `.`, and grab the first element by passing a 0.  Now, we have

```
0269-51581-0467
```

Go ahead and sort that little guy and you're good to go!

Comment: Thank you, I used a variant of your first answer. Just came here to `thank you` after finishing my work. I've done my task by splitting it on `-` and it gave me 4 strings, sorted out the 2nd and using the indices of that : using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948031/removing-non-unique-values-and-rearranging-vectors) and [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/160560-access-cell-array-inside-another-cell-array) question : I sorted out the other and than combined with `strcat` to get back complete URLs.