# Sort one vector based on other

Tags: r, sorting

I have 2 vectors,

```
x <- c (1,4,6,7,9,2)
y <- c (2,6,5,1,8,9)
```

I want to sort x and y both. y is dependent on x. The result I want is

```
x = (1,2,4,6,7,9)
y = (2,9,6,5,1,8)
```

I know that I can get index of sorting x as

```
sort(x, index.return=TRUE)$ix
```

How do I sort vector y?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568511/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use that as index

```
i1 <- sort(x, index.return=TRUE)$ix
```

Or with `order`

```
i1 <- order(x)
x[i1]
#[1] 1 2 4 6 7 9

y[i1]
#[1] 2 9 6 5 1 8
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Let me try and get back :)

Comment: i don't think this is correct; because the smallest value in x is 1 and it is in first place. but the smallest value of y is not in the first place.

Comment: @Z.Zhang The OP's question is to sort y based on the values of 'x' and not based on 'y'

Answer (score 3):

you are looking for `order()`. It generates an index based on the values in a vector. Using this index you can sort your `y` vector

```
y[order(x)]
# [1] 2 9 6 5 1 8
```

Be sure, however, that the vectors have the same length. Otherwise `NA`s will be generated

```
x <- c (1,4,6,7,9,2,3)
y <- c (2,6,5,1,8,9)
y[order(x)]
# [1]  2  9 NA  6  5  1  8
```

or some values will be lost

```
x <- c (1,4,6,7,9,2)
y <- c (2,6,5,1,8,9,3)
y[order(x)]
# [1] 2 9 6 5 1 8
```