# Rename variables based on values in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes, DF1 and DF2:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
                 V2 = factor(c("E", "F", "G", "H")),
                 Va3 = factor(c("I", "J", "K", "L")),
                 column = factor(c("M", "N", "O", "P")))

DF2 <- data.frame(N1 = factor(c("x", "V1", "V2", "y", "z", "Va3", "a", "column")),
                  N2 = factor(c("A", "var1", "random", "R", "Q", "nameofcolumn", "S", "varname4")))
```

I want to change the name of variables in `DF1` (`V1:column`) based on the value of the corresponding cell in `DF2$N2`, so that, e.g. `V2` becomes `random` and `column` becomes `varname4`.

Normally, I would just use `colnames(DF1) <- DF2$N2` if the variable names in `DF1` matched the cell values in `DF2`; but here I have those additional values. How can I rename the variables properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use `match`

```
names(DF1)=DF2$N2[match(names(DF1),DF2$N1)]
DF1
  var1 random nameofcolumn varname4
1    A      E            I        M
2    B      F            J        N
3    C      G            K        O
4    D      H            L        P
```

---

**Update**

```
names(DF1)[which(names(DF1)%in%DF2$N1)]=as.character(DF2$N2[match(names(DF1)[which(names(DF1)%in%DF2$N1)],DF2$N1)])
DF1
  var1 random nameofcolumn varname4 somethingelse
1    A      E            I        M             M
2    B      F            J        N             N
3    C      G            K        O             O
4    D      H            L        P             P
```

Comment: This is a great, elegant solution. And it works perfectly in this example, but it seems to have an unfortunate side effect of deleting the names of all columns in the a larger version of DF1 that do not have an equivalent in DF2$N2.

Comment: @KaC check the update , I adding one additional columns in DF1 somethingelse, which is not in the DF2

Answer (score 2):

With version 1.12.0 (on CRAN 13 Jan 2019), [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)'s `setnames()` function has gained a new parameter `skip_absent` to skip names in `old` that aren't present. `setnames()` does work with `data.frame` and `data.table` likewise.

```
data.table::setnames(DF1, as.character(DF2$N1), as.character(DF2$N2), skip_absent = TRUE)
DF1
```

> ```
>   var1 random nameofcolumn varname4
> 1    A      E            I        M
> 2    B      F            J        N
> 3    C      G            K        O
> 4    D      H            L        P
> ```

Or, with an additional column not included in `DF2`:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
                  V2 = factor(c("E", "F", "G", "H")),
                  Va3 = factor(c("I", "J", "K", "L")),
                  column = factor(c("M", "N", "O", "P")),
                  other = 1:4)
data.table::setnames(DF1, as.character(DF2$N1), as.character(DF2$N2), skip_absent = TRUE)
DF1
```

> ```
>   var1 random nameofcolumn varname4 other
> 1    A      E            I        M     1
> 2    B      F            J        N     2
> 3    C      G            K        O     3
> 4    D      H            L        P     4
> ```

Comment: I authored this additional parameter and it is precisely the reason why it was implemented - to prevent `setnames` from ceasing whenever a value wasn't present.  I would run this on enormous datasets and it would occasionally cease to function after a number of minutes because a value (column name) didn't exist in an automatically generated data frame (of which I had no control / prior knowledge).  I am glad to see `skip_absent` being required and implemented elsewhere in the community.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex). Based on your actual needs, the pattern that you need to extract values based on may change. Right now, I am extracting the "cells" that start with (`^` translates to that) `varname` and `*` means whatever comes next. Assuming that order of the variable names is also right.

***Note:*** based on first version of the question which had `varname#` as the column names.

```
colnames(DF1) <-  subset(DF2$N2, grepl("^varname*", DF2$N2))

str(DF1)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ varnames1: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2 3 4
# $ varname2 : Factor w/ 4 levels "E","F","G","H": 1 2 3 4
# $ varname3 : Factor w/ 4 levels "I","J","K","L": 1 2 3 4
# $ varname4 : Factor w/ 4 levels "M","N","O","P": 1 2 3 4
```

<sub>I am aware of the redundancy in my pattern. Just included both `*` and `^` to give OP some more insight.</sub>

***Update to answer edited question:*** Matching values in `N1` to find columns names in `N2`:

You can subset based on values in `N1` and `colnames(DF1)`:

```
subset(DF2, (N1 %in% colnames(DF1)))
#       N1           N2
# 2     V1         var1
# 3     V2       random
# 6    Va3 nameofcolumn
# 8 column     varname4
```

You can assign them as column names of `DF1` like below (you can try `$` operator as well):

```
colnames(DF1) <- DF2$N2[as.numeric(rownames(subset(DF2, (N1 %in% colnames(DF1)))))]
```

If the sorting was different in two dataframes, look at this thread: [Sort one vector based on another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568511/how-do-i-sort-one-vector-based-on-values-of-another)

Comment: Thank you. Now, I'm aware this is a different question, but what if there is no clear pattern? Is there a way to match variable names to row values simply based on location in DF2?

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. Much appreciated.