# Sort values of named vector A by vector B but keeping the order of names where possible

Tags: r, sorting, vector, indexing, matching

I have a named vector like that:

```
my_vec <- c("Max"= "England", "Manfred"= "Germany", "Ingolf"= "Germany", "Paul"= "England", "Peter"= "Germany", "Nina"= "Italy")
```

I need to sort this vector by countries as specified in another vector while keeping the order of the persons for a given country as before. So if the ordering of the countries is...

```
sort_scheme <- c("England", "Germany", "Italy")
```

... then my desired output is:

```
goal_vec <- c("Max"= "England", "Paul"= "England", "Manfred"= "Germany", "Ingolf"= "Germany", "Peter"= "Germany", "Nina"= "Italy")
```

As you can see the desired output has the same order of countries as in `sort_scheme` (England first, then Germany, then Italy) and, inside one country the original order of names is the same (for England Max comes first then Paul, and so on). The solution should be flexible for other characters (new names and countries) with base R. All I've come up with is incredibly cumbersome.

**Edit** I found this being a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568511/how-do-i-sort-one-vector-based-on-values-of-another) and voted to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `order`:

`my_vec[order(match(my_vec, sort_scheme))]`

```
      Max      Paul   Manfred    Ingolf     Peter      Nina 
"England" "England" "Germany" "Germany" "Germany"   "Italy"
```

---

As per @MerijnvanTilborg - if "nested" ordering using the vector names is required (which is not the case in the OP) we can use:
`my_vec[order(match(my_vec, sort_scheme), names(my_vec))]`

See `?order`:

> In the case of ties in the first vector, values in the second are used
> to break the ties.

Comment: Very nice solution, in addition you expand it a bit and use `my_vec[order(match(my_vec, sort_scheme), names(my_vec))]` to sort on country based on your sort_scheme and then also order if desired on the name itself.

Comment: The comment of @MerijnvanTilborg does not result in the expected output because it sorts the elements alphabetically but the names of `goal_vec` are not in alphabetic order. For example, Manfred comes before Ingolf in `goal_vec` in my question but not in `my_vec[order(match(my_vec, sort_scheme), names(my_vec))]`. Your original answer solves the problem as described.

Comment: @PuckFutin - yes, this is an addition just in case you need control on the "2nd level".

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a named value sorts the vector by its values and not its names. Assuming your sort_scheme is alphabetically from A-Z you can just use `sort` on your vector.

```
sort(my_vec)
#       Max      Paul   Manfred    Ingolf     Peter      Nina 
# "England" "England" "Germany" "Germany" "Germany"   "Italy"
```

Comment: This would be awesome but unfortunately it is just a coincidence that `sort_scheme` is alphabetical. In my situation it can be not alphabetical.